# Correct use of std::map as class member

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

In the past I always created a map like this:

```
class TestClass
{
    private:
        std::map<int,int> *mapA;
};

TestClass::TestClass
{
    mapA = new std::map<int,int>();
}

TestClass::~TestClass
{
    mapA->clear(); // not necessary
    delete mapA;
}
```

So, now I read all over the place at Stackoverflow: **avoid pointers as often as possible**

Currently I want to create the map without pointer and new (no need to delete the object by myself and less danger of getting some memory leak)!

```
class TestClass
{
    public:
        TestClass() : mapA() // this is also needed?
        {};
    private:
        std::map<int,int> mapA;
};
```

Any further steps for correct creation of the map necessary?

Thanks for any help and/or clarification!

Comment: I just noticed you edited in a mapA->clear() to your original destructor. This is not necessary - the map will clear itself during deconstruction.

Comment: You dont need to call `map::clear` in either case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope that's it, and you don't need to explicitly initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: I'm always surpised that although the pointerless code is *much* simpler than the pointer code, newbies always seem to go for the pointer version.

Comment: @john Maybe this is not so; it is only that those who go for the pointer get in trouble and we notice them.

Comment: @john Frequently people come over from Java, and since you have to new everything over in Java, they do the same in C++.

Comment: Andre, john: and from C, or course, the original home hell of pointers. @Gorpik: :-))

Comment: Why don't we need to initialize the map in the member initializer list ?

Comment: @Tesla123 Because class members are implicitly default constructed.

Answer (score 4):

As zennehoy says, it is not necessary to initialize the map in the `TestClass` constructor. 
Let me note a difference between the two implementations:

In the first one, the `TestClass`, as it is currently written, is not copyable without undesirable effects because the raw pointer to the dynamically allocated map is copied:

```
TestClass *A = new TestClass;      // A has a map
TestClass *B = new TestClass(A);   // B shares the map with A!

delete A; // this deletes A's map (in destructor)
delete B; // this deletes A's map again! wrong
```

In your second implementation, that does not happen because the map, and not just its address, is copied completely.

To solve that issue in your first implementation, you should use a shared pointer, or do the work yourself by implementing the `operator=` and the copy constructor. Or, if you want to really share the map between copied instances, you should implement a reference counting mechanism.